# Test suite for custom Scala collections?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is anyone aware of a test suite or framework for testing new collection classes?  Or tests of the standard collections that could be usefully repurposed?  It seems like there are many invariants that could be generically tested.

If it matters, I'm working on implementations of IndexedSeq and its kin - not linked-lists, sets, or maps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it would just take too much space in comments. I checked out scala from github (https://github.com/scala/scala) and tried to find any tests. After not being able to find something similar to what you were asking for I tried `find`:

```
# find test -iname "*collection*" -type f -exec wc -l {} \;

14 test/files/run/collection-stacks.check
38 test/files/run/collection-stacks.scala
64 test/files/run/collection-conversions.scala
58 test/files/run/unittest_collection.scala
11 test/files/run/collections-toSelf.scala
42 test/files/run/collections.check
125 test/files/run/collection-conversions.check
119 test/files/run/collections.scala
59 test/files/scalacheck/CheckCollections.scala
15 test/files/pos/collections.scala
```

As you can see all those files are pretty small, so I wonder where the tests are :).

Comment: Thanks - there are also several additional collection-library tests  in https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/test/files/scalacheck .  As far as I've looked, none are designed for reuse, but they can be mined for invariants.

Answer (score 0):

Look into what scala uses

http://www.scala-lang.org/contribute/partest-guide.html

It should be a starting point for you

Comment: This is interesting but only explains how they run tests, not where the tests are and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how easy it is to adapt to new custom collection classes, but

https://github.com/scala/scala-collections-laws

looks very interesting.